# Run init.d script in the context of the current user session

Tags: init.d

I'd like to run a script in init.d (on Fedora) in the context of the user session I'm logging in as.

I have a script called keyboard_deadkeys I wrote to set some deadkeys on my keyboard.  The script is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/julie/keymappings
```

I put it in the directory /etc/init.d so it will run at boot time.  It is also in /etc/rc.d/init.d

I changed the permissions to a+rwx for good measure.

When I boot; the deadkeys aren't set in the user's session.  When I then run the script manually; the keys are set.

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run the script at boot time, when no one is logged in, how could it modify anything in the user's session? :-)

You should run it from your .bash_profile startup script (or from /etc/profile, to run it for every user in the system).

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/questions/125165/local-user-login-script-fedora-linux

Your question is very similar to this one here.